# compute Sum of Sum in sql

Tags: sql

in SQL when I want to compute Sum of one column that is also Sum base on grouping, the total value is not correct.here I want to compute sum of Mand that is Sum(Qty) but the final result isn't correct.

```
Select Sum(Mand) from (Select TrackingFactor1 As Number ,SUM(Qty) As Mand from(
  Select  t.TrackingFactor1,SUM(
                          CASE 
                               WHEN Direction = 1 THEN t.MajorUnitQuantity
                               WHEN Direction = 2 THEN -t.MajorUnitQuantity
                               ELSE 0
                          END
                      ) AS Qty,
                      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY i.Date, i.VoucherCreationDate, v.InventoryVoucherID, i.InventoryVoucherItemID) AS 
                      RowNumber
                      from LGS3.InventoryVoucher AS v
                      INNER JOIN LGS3.InventoryVoucherItem i  ON  v.InventoryVoucherID = I.InventoryVoucherRef
                      LEFT OUTER JOIN LGS3.InventoryVoucherItemTrackingFactor t  ON  i.InventoryVoucherItemID = t.InventoryVoucherItemRef
                      GROUP BY
                      v.InventoryVoucherID,
                      v.Number,
                      i.Date,
                      i.VoucherCreationDate,
                      i.InventoryVoucherItemID,
                       i.CounterpartEntityText,
                      t.TrackingFactor1 ,
                      v.FiscalYearRef
                      )As A
                    group  by TrackingFactor1 
                    Having SUM(Qty)>0) As AA
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results please.

Comment: Whats the use of ROW_NUMBER in the query?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: some thing like this   92    129000  / 93     299309 / 95      68838  we want to compute sum of this three value (129000+299309+68838)